# Присоединить массив к элементу другого массива в PHP

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива:

```
$m1= Array
(
[0] => 123
[1] => 456
)

$m2= Array
(
[0] => 
      array 
      (
      [num]=123
      [val]=fff
      )
[1] => 
      array 
      (
      [num]=123
      [val]=ccc
      )
[2] => 
      array 
      (
      [num]=123
      [val]=eee
      )
[3] => 
      array 
      (
      [num]=456
      [val]=asd
      )
[4] => 
      array 
      (
      [num]=456
      [val]=ghj
      )
)
```

Возможно ли какими-нибудь штатными функциями в PHP получить результат в виде такого массива, взяв за основу два предыдущих:

```
$m3 = Array 
(
[0] =>
      array
      (
      [num]=123;
      [values]= fff, ccc, eee
      )
[1] =>
      array
      (
      [num]=456;
      [values]= asd, ghj
      )
)
```

Comment: пробегитесь вы по второму массиву, склейте значения с одинаковыми номерами в новый массив, а там уже примените логику из первого. готовой магии не случится, а если случится, то callback-методы все равно писать придется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, штатными функциями такого добиться не получится.
Вот реализация:

```
$m3 = [];
foreach($m1 => $key as $num) {
    if (isset($m2[$key])) { // запишет только если соответствует ключу в массиве $m2
        $m3[$key]['num'] = $num;
        $m3[$key]['values'] = $m2[$key]['val'];
    }
}
```